# Angular JS and raido buttons

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

Does anyone know how to check a radio button by default using Angular JS? I tried doing

```
<input type= "radio" value= "point" checked= "checked"></input>
<input type= "radio" value= "range"></input>
```

Which worked, but then when I tried to add a little Angular JS into the mix

```
<input type= "radio" value= "point" ng-model= "mode" checked= "checked"></input>
<input type= "radio" value= "range" ng-model= "mode"></input>
```

This stopped working, ie.. when I loaded the page, there was no longer anything checked by default. Does anyone know angular's way of ensuring that something is checked by default? I need something to be checked, because the html that I display upon loading the page will eventually be tied to whichever of the two radio buttons is selected.

Thanks

Comment: use different models and set them to true in the controller.

Comment: like

$scope.point_mode = true

something like this?

Comment: @Zack - Set the model to the value you want checked, ex `point`

Comment: @Zack yes, though better use tymeJVs solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `ng-model` equal to the `value` of the radio you want checked.

```
<input type= "radio" value= "point" ng-model= "mode"></input>
<input type= "radio" value= "range" ng-model= "mode"></input>

$scope.mode = "point";
```

Comment: follow up question, is there a way to hide a div element using Angular JS until the range radio button is selected